# "Work Details" functionality isn't recognizing efforts from Bugs/PBI

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to use the functionality of "Work details" for my sprints in DevOps, in order to have the automatic calculation of team remaining capacity for each sprint.
I set capacity for the team and they all have Bugs/Product backlog items assigned with "Effort" and "Remaining work" fields populated.
Our "Effort" field is specified with days.
Unfortunately the efforts are not being calculated inside the "Work details" panel, I only get total hours.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L338F.png)

I tried to use other fields instead of "Effort" like "Story points" or "Original estimate" but no one worked.
I also read documentation but I couldn't find a clear solution/explanation for this.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Work details` is used only for tasks planned for the sprint. You plan hours that developers may be available. Then you create tasks and assign them to a specific developer. `Work details` recalculates available and planned hours.

[Balance work across the team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/adjust-work?view=azure-devops#balance-work-across-the-team)

Comment: Yes, the sprint that I'm working on has already planned PBI/bugs for it (assigned of course to developers). Is the problem the type of object? Can't I use PBI/bugs instead of tasks? Thank you

Comment: @MonicaP.  _Can't I use PBI/bugs instead of tasks?_ - No. There is no similar functionality for PBI/bugs. You may try using Kanban boards with WIP limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-quickstart?view=azure-devops#set-wip-limits

Comment: Oh, I see. That's clear. Thank you for your help!